# Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_cassandra.so'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, cassandra, mariadb

I can't install the **cassandra** plugin in **mariadb 10.0.20**, 
I tried with this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> INSTALL PLUGIN cassandra SONAME 'ha_cassandra.so';
```

> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library
>   '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_cassandra.so' (errno: 2, cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory)

```
MariaDB [(none)]> INSTALL SONAME 'ha_cassandra.so';
```

> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library
>   '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_cassandra.so' (errno: 2, cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory)

But in both cases I get the same error.  Please help me.

I use **Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit**s and **mariadb 10.0.20**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually mariadb  downloads page offers two x86_64.tar.gz files: "mariadb-10.0.10-linux-x86_64.tar.gz" and "mariadb-10.0.10-linux-x86_64.tar.gz (requires GLIBC_2.14+)".  So hopefully if you not downloaded the glibc  version  try it out, it should have the all extended storage engines like  tokudb,cassandra etc.,

```
source : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/tokudb-engine-installation-problem/
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem because the MariaDB installation instructions on this page could be confusing for Ubuntu users:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-14-04

For Ubuntu installations, be sure to first create a repository:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common

apt-key adv --recv-keys –keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db

add-apt-repository 'deb http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'

apt-get update

apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Finish the installation by running:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Conclustion: If you don't update the repository first, you'll end up with an old version of MariaDB, which doesn't contain the Cassandra Plugin, and will thus result in the errors noted above.